# DataInputStream who close stream if IOException

Tags: java, datainputstream

In all examples everybody can find code like this:

```
DataInputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = new DataInputStream( new FileInputStream("file.data"));
    int i = inputStream.readInt();
    inputStream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
    //print message File not found
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace() }
```

When this code met `FileNotFound` exception, `inputStream` was not open, so it doesn't need to be closed.

But why when `IOException` mets in that catch block I don't see `inputStream.close()`. This operation did's automatically when input data exception throws? Because if programm has problem with input this means that stream already open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, close operation doesn't invoke automatically. For this purposes use `try-with-resources` introduced in Java 7:

```
try (DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream( new FileInputStream("file.data"))) {
    int i = inputStream.readInt();
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace() }
```

**UPD:** Explanation: `DataInputStream` implements `AutoCloseable` interface. That means, that in construction `try-with-resources` Java automatically will call `close()` method of `inputStream` in hidden finally block.

Comment: what do you mean "try-catch-with-resources" introduced in Java7?  in your code part I don't see inputStream.close() operator. you mean to let closing for Java?

Comment: @LesyaMakhova I suggest you to read about this construction here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 2):

```
DataInputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = new DataInputStream( new FileInputStream("file.data"));
    int i = inputStream.readInt();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
  //print message File not found
} catch (IOException e) { 
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
  if(null!=inputStream)
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if the file not found exception occurs the steam is open, you would simply need to close it again as well.

You should always add a finally block in your try catch and close the stream. Finally will always execute if there is an exception

```
 finally {
            if(reader != null){
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //do something clever with the exception
                }
            }
            System.out.println("--- File End ---");
        }
```